# Multithreading Java synchronize access without synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am writing a Java program that simulates the behavior of a train station. Each station receives pods and sends them either when they are full (4 persons) or after 2 seconds. My pods are sent using the synchronized sendPod() method. In my example, I have 3 stations A, B, C. A has a connection (represented by a tube) to B and C. Stations B and C have a connection to A. Each tube has a duration (int) that represents the ride duration (I used Thread.sleep() to do so).

With my current implementation if the station A sends a pod to the station B it will not send the next pod to station C until the pod sent to station B has arrived because my method sendPod() is synchronized. I would like to know how I could solve this problem so that a station would send all its pods one after the other (without waiting for the previous to arrive) and keep a consistent state in the data (number of persons at the station,...).

Thanks for your help :)

Launcher.java

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Station stationA = new Station("Station A", 6);
        Station stationB = new Station("Station B", 0);
        Station stationC = new Station("Station C", 0);

        List<Tube> tubesA = new ArrayList<Tube>();
        tubesA.add(new Tube(stationA, stationB, 3));
        tubesA.add(new Tube(stationA, stationC, 2));
        
        List<Tube> tubesB = new ArrayList<Tube>();
        tubesB.add(new Tube(stationB, stationA, 3));

        List<Tube> tubesC = new ArrayList<Tube>();
        tubesC.add(new Tube(stationC, stationA, 2));

        stationA.setTubes(tubesA);
        stationB.setTubes(tubesB);
        stationC.setTubes(tubesC);
        
        stationA.pods.add(new Pod(0));
        stationA.pods.add(new Pod(0));
            
        stationA.start();
    }
}
```

Station.java

```
public class Station extends Thread {

    String name;
    int persons;
    int maxPods;
    List<Tube> tubes;
    List<Pod> pods = new ArrayList<Pod>();

    public Station(String name, int persons) {
        this.name = name;
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public void setTubes(List<Tube> tubes) {
        this.tubes = tubes;
        maxPods = tubes.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " [persons=" + persons + ", number of pods=" + pods.size() + "]";
    }

    public Tube getNextFreeTube() {
        var random = new Random();
        while(true) {
            int index = random.nextInt(tubes.size());
            if(tubes.get(index).isFree) {
                if(tubes.get(index).destination.isFull()){
                    System.out.println("Destination " + tubes.get(index).destination + " is full. Try another one...");
                } else {
                    return tubes.get(index);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(tubes.get(index) + " is not free. Try another one...");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return this.pods.size() >= this.maxPods;
    }

    public synchronized void receivePod(Pod p) {
        this.persons += p.passengerNumber;
        this.pods.add(p);
        System.out.println(p + " arrived at " + this);
        p.passengerNumber = 0;
        notify();
    }
    
    public void sendPods() {
        Iterator<Pod> iter = pods.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Pod p = iter.next();
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendPod(p);
                }
            }.start();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    
    public synchronized void sendPod(Pod p) {
        Tube nextTube = getNextFreeTube();
        if (persons < 4) {
            try {
                System.out.println(this.name + " is waiting 2 seconds for more people to board");
                wait(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        p.passengerNumber = Math.min(4, persons);
        this.persons -= p.passengerNumber;
        nextTube.send(p);
    }

    public synchronized void startStation() {
        System.out.println("Starting station " + this);
        if (pods.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println(this.name + " is waiting for a pod to arrive");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        sendPods();
    }
    
    public void run(){  
        startStation();
    }  
}
```

Tube.java

```
public class Tube {

    boolean isFree = true;
    Station origin;
    Station destination;
    int duration;

    public Tube(Station origin, Station destination, int duration) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public synchronized void send(Pod p) {
        try {
            this.isFree = false;
            System.out.println("Sending " + p + " from " + origin.name + " [persons=" + origin.persons + "] to " + destination.name + ". Ride duration is " + this.duration + "sec...");
            Thread.sleep(this.duration * 1000);
            destination.receivePod(p);
            this.isFree = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tube { from " + origin.name + " to " + destination.name + "}";
    }
}
```

Pod.java

```
public class Pod {
    int passengerNumber = 0;

    public Pod(int passengerNumber) {
        this.passengerNumber = passengerNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pod [passengerNumber=" + passengerNumber + "]";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Stations should not extend Thread. A station is not a thread.

Comment: If you want to do this without synchronization, use a `BlockingQueue` instead of `List`s.